# Почему не срабатывает событие @click?

Tags: jquery, vue.js

Событие `select_list_currentClick(e)` должно переключать класс `open` для того, чтобы появлялся селект как справа на скрине
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Но оно почему-то срабатывает очень редко, приходится несколько раз перезагружать страницу, хотя мое приложение вообще без перезагрузки должно работать... Такие селекты у меня на каждой странице, поэтому даже если при перезагрузке удалось на первой страницы навешать класс и селект сработал, то при переходе на другую страницу уже ничего не работает. Хотя он у меня подключен одним компонентом к обоим этим страницам

Верстка

```
<div class="selected_relative">
                    <div class="select_list_wrapper">
                        <div class="select_list_current" @click="select_list_currentClick($event)">
                            <span class="label">Сортировать:</span>
                            <span class="select_list_current_item">По популярности</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="select_list">
                            <div class="select_list_radio"><input type="radio" id="by_popular" name="sort_list" checked><label for="by_popular"><span>По популярности</span> </label></div>
                            <div class="select_list_radio"><input type="radio" id="by_price" name="sort_list"><label for="by_price"><span>По цене</span> </label></div>
                            <div class="select_list_radio"><input type="radio" id="by_date" name="sort_list"><label for="by_date"><span>По новизне</span> </label></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

событие

```
select_list_currentClick(e) {
                    var $this = $(e.target);
                    if(this.$route.name !== 'fhgkgkjg') {
                        $this.parent('.select_list_wrapper').toggleClass('open');
                        $this.parent().find('.select_list').slideDown("slow");
                    }

            },
```

P. S. эту абракадабру `this.$route.name !== 'fhgkgkjg'` прилепила в надежде, что это заставит код при изменении маршрута навешивать класс:(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваша главная ошибка в том, что вы подходите к vue.js с неверным (для данного framework'a) мышлением взятым из jQuery. В Vue изменение DOM напрямую крайне не приветствуется и производится только в редких случаях.
Вашу задачу Вы можете реализовать прикрепив атрибут `:class` (https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html) на объект DOM.

```
<div class="select_list_wrapper" :class="{'open': opened}">
</div>
```

И далее, изменяя значение переменной `opened` вы сможете скрывать или показывать свой элемент так, как вам надо.

```
new Vue({
    data: { opened: false },
    methods: { select_list_currentClick() { this.opened = !this.opened; } }
});
```

По поводу анимации стоит почитать соответствующий раздел на официальном сайте:

https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html

По поводу так называемого "Jquery мышления" стоит прочитать данный ответ на SO (англ. язык):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/thinking-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background

Comment: Спасибо, все сделала, как вы указали и заработало:)